# How to avoid column names that are repeatedly appearing in a live DataFrame?

Tags: python, dataframe

the below python program shows current datetime according to timezone in a DataFrame. The only problem is, the column names are unnecessarily appearing after every new row of data. Please refer to the image below to see the output

[image: DataFrame output]

What else do I need to add in this program?

```
import time
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime
import pytz

while (True):
IST = pytz.timezone('Asia/Kolkata')
datetime_ist = datetime.now(IST) 
Datetime=datetime_ist.strftime('%Y/%m/%d %H:%M:%S')

df= pd.DataFrame([Datetime])
df.columns = ['Datetime']
display(df)
time.sleep(1)
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is how you are showing the `DataFrame`.
If you want only the data in the `df` you should use `at` like this:

```
df.at[0, 'Datetime']
```

Answer (score 0):

This is because every new "row" in your case is an entirely new `DataFrame`. What else could you ever expect?

You can't really build and display a DataFrame incrementally like this in Jupyter. Unfortunately I don't think there is any option to turn off displaying column headers without manually writing some HTML formatting code.

In your case, it might make more sense to just `print()` the output you need.